# Custom tags on Tiff Image: Private Tags

Tags: c++, libtiff

I can insert the tags on the image. The problem is that every tag that i insert stays with the name "PrivateTag" on LeadTools or the number of the tag on AsTiffTagViewer. Only the name of the tag.

I'm following the example of this guy:
[Adding custom tags to a TIFF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059421/adding-custom-tags-to-a-tiff-file)

The code is not so different.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: TIFF spec states that tags 32768 or higher are "private tags", which means their names vary widely from one organization to another. If the TIFF viewer is not from the same organization that wrote the tag, it will ignore it. Your code defines the tags starting with 65000, which is in the private range. If you're using the LEADTOOLS Tag Editor, it has no way of knowing what you mean by them. If you want a viewer to assign specific names to these tags, write your own TIFF viewer or tag editor. One way to do that is to use the [LEADTOOLS imaging SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging-pro).

Comment: Yes, i had to learn that the hard way. I had to develop a TIFF viewer. Your comment answers my question. Please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIFF spec states that tags 32768 or higher are "private tags", which means their names vary widely from one organization to another. If the TIFF viewer is not from the same organization that wrote the tag, it will ignore it. Your code defines the tags starting with 65000, which is in the private range. If you're using the LEADTOOLS Tag Editor, it has no way of knowing what you mean by them. If you want a viewer to assign specific names to these tags, write your own TIFF viewer or tag editor. One way to do that is to use the [LEADTOOLS imaging SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging-pro).